# Child Custody : Cases supporting Father as primary care giver or shared care and control

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, common-law, family-law, children

Does anyone have Court of Appeal cases where by custody is awarded to the father or shared custody is awarded?

Basically Father proposed a shared care and control parenting arrangement but mother is refusing to share and only willing give access for 1 day a week.

The case is in a common law jurisdiction, hence court of appeal cases will be most helpful.

Basically the father argument is the child love both parents and the both parents love the child. He is offering a care arrangement that allow both parents to play a part in his life.

Child age 2 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Child custody is decided in the best interests of the *child*. Joint custody with equal access is the *default* assumption of the child's best interest and the court will generally approve any plan that gives effect to it.

Hire a solicitor who specialises in family law **now**.

Comment: sadly that is not true in Singapore common law jurisdiction. We need to present cases from common law jurisdiction to back up our points.

Comment: @user4127 your tags say United Kingdom- why are you talking about Singapore?

Comment: Because there aren't many in Singapore. So I look towards UK or Australia.